# Framework7: Login redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

When user visits login.html page, localStorage is used to check if a user is logged in. The page should redirect to profile.html and display notofication message.
The message is displayed, but the page (login.html) is the same..

```
if( localStorage.user_login ) {
    mainView.router.loadPage({url:'profile.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true });

myApp.addNotification( {
        message: 'Welcome '+ localStorage.user_username +'!'
      } );
}
```

How can i make the page redirect if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 3):

put this before myApp framework7 initialization.

```
    $$(document).on('pageInit', function (e) {
       var page = e.detail.page;
       if (page.name === 'index') {
         try{
           var storedData = window.localStorage['f7form-'+ 'idofyourloginform'];
          if(storedData) {
              //do your ajax login request here
              // if successful do your login redirect  
                 mainView.router.loadPage({url:'profile.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true });
           }
       }
     );
```

Comment: But mainView is not initialized yet, so you won't be able to navigate in your view correctly

Answer (score 1):

login page ajax post and response in Framework7 with jquery

inside your my-app.js file use like this codes

```
myApp.onPageInit('sign-in', function(page) {
$('#loginb').click(function() {
    $('#loginb').html('Please Wait...');
    var fuid = $('#uid').val();
    var fpass = $('#pass').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chklogin.php',
        data: {
            "uid": fuid,
            "pass": fpass
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(returnedData) {
            $('#loginb').html(returnedData);

            if (returnedData == "Success") {
                mainView.router.load({
                    url: 'deshboard.php',
                    ignoreCache: true
                });
            } else {
                mainView.router.load({
                    url: 'login.php',
                    ignoreCache: true
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Login page, use like this codes:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="button button-fill color-blue close-login-screen" @click="signIn">Log In </a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
return {
  methods: {
    signIn: function () {
      var $ = this.$;
      var app = this.$app;
      var username = $('input#demo-username-1').val();
      var password = $('input#demo-password-2').val();

      app.request.post('http://localhost:4103/api/User/Login?username='+username+'&password='+password, function (data) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj);
        console.log(obj.success);

        if (obj.success) {
          app.data.IsLogin=true;
          app.data.UserName='salman';
          app.views.main.router.navigate(obj.RedirectUrl);       
        } else {
          app.dialog.alert(obj.Message , function () {});
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
myApp.closeModal('.login-screen.modal-in')
```

before

```
 mainView.router.loadPage({url:'profile.html', ignoreCache:true, reload:true })
```

That should solve the problem.

Comment: Tried adding the closeModal, but with no effect.
I am not using a modal for login - just a "plain" page.

Comment: Got it! I thought you were using f7's modal helper. Is 'profile.html' at the same level as the login page? Do they reside in the same folder?

Comment: Another advice: try checking the network traffic in your favorite browser. That will help identify whether f7 tried a get and received a 404 or something like that.

Comment: Yeas, profile.html and login.html are in the same folder.
Outputting to console before and after the mainView.router - both output is printed, no redirect..

Comment: When you hit F12 and go to the Networking, in case you are using Chrome, does the browser show the Get request? By the way, can you show the html of the profile page?

Comment: No Get request shown for the new page. Only the original (login.html).

Comment: Html for profile
`<div data-page="profile" class="page navbar-transparent">
 <div class="navbar navbar-transparent">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
   <div class="left"><a href="index.html" class="back link ripple-black"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i></a></div>
   <div class="center">Profile</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="page-content">
  </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this function with route name: 
`app.views.main.router.navigate('/profile');`

But make sure `app` is which you initialize project such as:

```
var app = new Framework7({....});
```