# framework7 Login page

Tags: javascript, phonegap, html-framework-7

I am trying to redirect my app at the beginning if a var is present on LocalStorage. If not then the user should fill the login page. Success at login and the user is redirected to page2.html

Tried with window.location.href and it doesn't work.

Can someone please help me with his matter?

Thanks

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161998/framework7-login-redirect

Comment: add code that helps. which version of f7 you are using

Comment: Try this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48839850/7189547

Comment: after fixing a few things on the code it works. Strange because it worked on chrome but it didn't work on android. Now I have some alerts spread on the script but they don't work on IOS.

I am using Phonegap Developer APP to test the app.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = new Framework7({    
  on: {
      pageInit: function() {
           if(localStorage.loggedIn != 1 || localStorage.loggedIn == 'undefined'){
           //not logged in , redirect to login page
                 this.router.navigate('/login-screen-page/');
           }else{
           // Login 
            this.router.navigate('/dashboard-page/');
           }
        }
      }     
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.router.navigate('/login-screen-page/');` to `app.views.main.router.navigate("/login-screen-page/")`